# Divide elements of each element of a vector with subsequent elements of the same vector

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a vector of 91 items.  From this vector, I want to derive a new vector in which each element is divided by each subsequent element in the vector.

For example, if the vector was

```
[2,4,6,8]
```

then I would want these operations

```
2/4, 2/6, 2/8, 4/6, 4/8, 6/8
```

which would give me

```
[0.5, 0.33, 0.25, 0.66, 0.5, 0.75]
```

With my vector containing 91 elements, the result should have 4095 elements (using the combinations formula *nCr = n! / r!(n-r)!*).

I am assuming I need to create nested For loops since variable `j` (denominator) increments multiple times for each one time variable `i` (numerator) increments.  Then I need to do the division, and append each result to a new vector (list).

So I have a few small pieces of the solution (I think):

```
my_new_vector = []  
For i in my_vector  
For j in my_vector  
quotient = i/j  
my_new_vector.append
```

but after that I'm just not clear on how to construct the nested For loops.

Comment: Maybe the first step would be to convert the pseudocode you have written to actual Python code that runs without error. Then you can see if it does what you want and what you need to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rather close, you indeed need two imbricated loops:

```
test = [2,4,6,8]
ans = []

for i in range(len(test)): # for each value of the array
    for j in range(i+1, len(test)): # We go from the next value to the end of the array.
        ans.append(test[i]/test[j])
```

Don't hesitate to print `test[i]` and `test[j]` to see better how it works.

Comment: Thank you very much Waelmio - I had a feeling that range had a part to play but didn't know.  The code you propose makes perfect sense and I am just trying it now ...

Comment: Just tried it with my vector of 91 elements and got the 4,095 results expected.  I can't tell you how happy it made me to see the numbers come up and the result verified.  Whew!  Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Combinations from itertools can do that for you directly:

```
from itertools import combinations

numbers = [2,4,6,8]
divisions = [a/b for a,b in combinations(numbers,2)]

print(divisions)
# [0.5, 0.3333333333333333, 0.25, 0.6666666666666666, 0.5, 0.75]
```

if you don't want to use a library, you can make the loop in a more Pythonic way like this:

```
divisions = []
for i,a in enumerate(numbers[:-1],1):
    divisions.extend(a/b for b in numbers[i:])

print(divisions) # [0.5, 0.3333333333333333, 0.25, 0.6666666666666666, 0.5, 0.75]
```